# add custom marker(square) to Gmap

Tags: c#, gmap.net

Basically I want to draw a filled square and add it (and use it) as a marker to Gmap. I tried drawing a square and use it as a bitmap but it asks me for the x y coordinates and I don't know what values to put for that because the marker already uses lat/long. I am trying this but the position of the square is not right.I want to square to appear on the specified lat/long.

```
Bitmap flag = new Bitmap(50, 50);
gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingHybridMapProvider.Instance;
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
Graphics fg = Graphics.FromImage(flag);
fg.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 100, 100, 50, 50);
GMapOverlay markerOverlay = new GMapOverlay(NametextBox.Text);
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528),flag);
markerOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
gmap.Overlays.Add(markerOverlay);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

To draw a filled square you follow following steps:

1. Right click on project settings.
2. Go to resources > add resource > new image.
3. Double click on new created image.
4. A blank page opens. Draw whatever you like and save it.

For plotting I used the following example:

```
GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528), new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.image8));
gmap.Overlays.Add(markers);   // overlay added
markers.Markers.Add(marker);
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [GMap.NET Tutorial – Maps, markers and polygons](http://www.websofia.com/2013/02/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/)

The code they provide for custom markers and its assignment to an overlay is the following:

```
GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528), GMarkerGoogleType.green);
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, the issue is not the creation of the bitmap itself, but that the flag *does not appear in the correct location*.  In order to make it appear in the correct location, you will have to modify the `Offset` property of the `Marker` object.

```
Bitmap flag = new Bitmap(50, 50);
gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingHybridMapProvider.Instance;
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
Graphics fg = Graphics.FromImage(flag);
fg.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 100, 100, 50, 50);
GMapOverlay markerOverlay = new GMapOverlay(NametextBox.Text);
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528),flag);
marker.Offset = new Point(-flag.Width/2, -flag.Height/2);  // Set point to middle of bitmap
markerOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
gmap.Overlays.Add(markerOverlay);
```